# Android/Java SQL database independence from entity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dao

I have a low experience in DB design and development with SQL.

I have Entity **User** :

```
public class User {
    String name;
    String secondName;
}
```

and **DAO** for this :

```
public interface UserDAO {
    // save
    void persistUser(User user);
    // obtain from DB
    User retrieveUser();
}
```

Implementation :

```
public class LibraryUserDAO implements UserDAO{

    /** SQL database actually*/    
    private SQLiteOpenHelper database;

    void persistUser(User user){
        // saving to DB
    }

    User retrieveUser(){
        // obtain from DB
    }
}
```

And i have a question.

> Is it possible to make saving to DB process independent for User class changes?

For example : now, as you can see i have 2 fields - **name** and **secondName**

Saving now :

```
    SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = database.getWritableDatabase();
    writableDatabase.beginTransaction();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", user.name);
    cv.put("secondName", user.secondName);

    writableDatabase.insert("users", null, cv);
    writableDatabase.close();
```

I want that when you add a new field (for ex. `year`) to the class `User`, in the database, this field is automatically added as a new column in the database (if not).
So always leave class `SQLiteOpenHelper` unchanged.(If it possible of course).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using some ORM for Android, for example [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) or [GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/). Then you won't have to worry about structure changes because you don't have to manually map POJOs to DB tables.

Comment: Is the backward-process supporting? I mean add & delete field\column options.

Comment: @ssh You have to implement it yourself in SQLiteOpenHelper but you don't have to change your save/fetch code.

Comment: Look like that it unreal task today :)

Comment: @ssh Noone told it would be fast :) I personally use ORMlite, when you get used to it - it's very fast and reliable tool for Android Developer.

Comment: Ok, it make sense. I will try. 
If it will be useful tool - this answer will be approved)

Comment: @ssh So I'm waiting for your feedback. Have a nice day.

Comment: @ssh How are you goind with Android ORMs? Any progress ?